# Gmail api - browser quickstart error: bad request

Tags: javascript, gmail, gmail-api

I followed [Google gmail api browser quickstart](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/quickstart/js) step by step, but when I try to open index.html I get the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "errors": [
      {
        "domain": "usageLimits",
        "reason": "keyInvalid",
        "message": "Bad Request"
      }
    ],
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Bad Request"
  }
}
```

=(

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I realize `API_KEY` is not the `secret key` from OAuth Credential process. So, I suppose you need to generate an `API_KEY` after generate a `CLIENT_ID`.

Comment: I would upvote this 1000x if I could. THE CLIENT SECRET IS NOT THE `apiKey`. Instead I had to create a seperate Api Key from the dashboard

Answer (score 0):

If you are not planning to use the API Key, kindly remove it in the request:

```
  function initClient() {
    gapi.client.init({
      apiKey: API_KEY, ///this one, since you didn't provide any value it will return an error.
      clientId: CLIENT_ID,
      discoveryDocs: DISCOVERY_DOCS,
      scope: SCOPES
    }).then(function () {
      // Listen for sign-in state changes.
      gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.listen(updateSigninStatus);

      // Handle the initial sign-in state.
      updateSigninStatus(gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance().isSignedIn.get());
      authorizeButton.onclick = handleAuthClick;
      signoutButton.onclick = handleSignoutClick;
    }, function(error) {
      appendPre(JSON.stringify(error, null, 2));
    });
  }
```

That should eliminate the issue you are encountering. My suggestion would be provide a valid API key from the console or remove it from the request (not sure how it will behave since in the quickstart they require both client ID and API key).